# Not displaying elements from stack

Tags: java, stack

So I have written this JAVA-program for stack and the problem is I cant display the elements using the display() method which I used in the code.

here is my Stack class.

```
public class Stack {
//members
private int top;
private int size;
private int[] a;
private int i;

//constructor
public Stack() {
    this.top = -1;
    this.size = 5;
    this.a = new int[size];
}

private boolean isempty() {
    if(top == -1) {
        System.out.println("Stack Underflow");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isfull() {
    if(top == size-1) {
        System.out.println("Stack Overflow");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void push(int n) {
if(isempty()) {
    top+=1;
    a[top] = n;
    }
}

public void pop() {
    if(isfull()) {
        System.out.println("popped : "+ a[top]);
        top-=1;         
    }
}

public void display() {
    for(i=0;i<top;i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

}
}
```

here is the main method class

```
public class Stackex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.push(2);
    s.push(4);
    s.display();
}

}
```

when I try to execute what is get is **"Stack underflow"** from the ***isempty()*** and nothing is displayed after that. Please help me where I need to correct this code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'll have a look at the code in a minute, but the step I would strongly suggest you take next is stepping through the code in a debugger, and editing the question with the results of that. Look carefully at the state at all times, and see when it becomes something you didn't expect. In the future, it would be better to do this *before* asking a question, as part of your research. Additionally, it doesn't help that the code you've posted is invalid: your real code definitely doesn't have `private int ijk]kkkk`.

Comment: A couple of things to note: 1) It's expected that `isempty()` will print "Stack Underflow" when `push` is called for the first time. It's an odd message though - normally that should only happen when `pop` is called on an empty stack. 2) `push()` will only actually push a single value - because after that, the stack isn't empty.

Comment: ``private int ijk]kkkk`` ??

Comment: im sorry  the ijk]kkk is actually "i" , when i try to edit the code it shows " i " and everything is normal, but when i posted here it is showing ijk]kkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix methods `push` & `display`:

```
public void push(int n) {
    if (!isfull()) {
        top += 1;
        a[top] = n;
    }
}

public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++) {
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `push` only pushes if `isempty` returns `true`.

So the first push succeeds and sets top to 0.

The second push never happens because `isempty` returns false.

So when you go to `display` your `for` loop never iterates, because `top` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are some compilation errors to fix first.
In the method `display` the `i` is not declared, fix it like this:

```
public void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) { // add int i = 0
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

Than change this:

```
private int[] a;;
private int ijk]kkkk
```

To this:

```
private int[] a;
```

Now your issue is because `isempty` returns false. So change the push method like this:

```
public void push(int n) {
    if (!isfull()) {
        top += 1;
        a[top] = n;
    }
}
```

When you add an element you want to check that the stack is not full.